# init.d fails with tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, server, monit

Im using tomcat on ubuntu server, and Im trying to use monit to keep it alive always.
But my problem is that monit dont work because

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat start
```

Throws this error:

```
touch: cannot touch '/opt/tomcat/latest/logs/catalina.out': Permission denied
/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/catalina.sh: 467: /opt/tomcat/latest/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /opt/tomcat/latest/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

If I give permissions 777 to catalina.out, tomcat dont work. But if I change the permissions to 755 I cant start with init.d

How can I solve it?

This is my "monit" code:

```
check process tomcat with pidfile "/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/temp/tomcat.pid"
      start program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat start"
      stop program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat stop"
      if failed port 8080 for 5 cycles then restart
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per default Monit is executed as root, but the `Permission denied` message might indicate that your Monit is **not** ran as root.

I see two solutions:

1. Execute Monit as root
2. Add a `/usr/bin/sudo` before your init script like

```
start program = "/usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat start"
```